# Gnuplot, plot in polar coordinates

Tags: plot, gnuplot, polar-coordinates

I have a file with 17294 particles (17294 lines) and for each particle I have θ,r in 2 columns. Here are the coordinates of the first 4 particles (radians,AU):

```
0.49270177616816235        2.5620755754079405
0.90238849710652080        2.5619357395318492
-0.40974974698351807       2.5078418996893919
1.2044083323780090         2.5701067236161976
```

I am trying to create a plot (via Gnuplot) with my data, the radius of the particles (distance from the Sun) is from 2.5 to 8 AU and when I plot I get only half of the disk:

[image: HalfDisk]

I want to create the whole disk, I know that radius isn't negative, so I tried to:

```
set rrange[8:8]
```

but it didn't work.

How can I do this ?

Comment: what do you get if you type `show trange`?

Comment: i entered gnuplot, i typed `set polar` then `show trange` and here you go:

 set trange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently [-10.0000:10.0000] )

Comment: you don't show your code. A minimal, reduced example would help a lot. Do you somewhere set your trange, e.g. `set trange [-pi/2:pi/2]`? What is the range of θ values in the first column? From 0 to 2*pi or -pi/2 to +pi/2?

Comment: There is no code to show....i just have the data. I changed the θ from radians to degrees, so i have θ [0:360] in the first column (or [0:2π] if you wish), but the plot is stil the same

Comment: The sample data you show clearly does not have [0:360] in the first column, since the third line is negative.  Are you sure about the range?

Comment: something must be "wrong" with your data (or your conversion). If we don't have the data, it will be difficult to make further guesses. Have you tried `reset session` at the beginning?

Comment: Something was indeed wrong, i fixed it and now i have the plot that i want. Thank you very much for your help